# chain scheduled tasks java spring

Tags: java, spring, task

Every 5 minutes, 2 tasks run, one that updates, one that calculates. 
The one that updates should always run first, but doesn't have to know anything about the calculator and visa versa.

Is there any way to manage this in a clean way without calling the other task from within.

After advice, this is my solution.

```
@PostConstruct
public void scheduleRunnableWithTrigger() {
    logger.info("init scheduler");
    scheduleTasks.schedule(() -> {
        if(init.getIsInitialzed()) {
            databaseUpdater.updatePrices();
            for (ITechnicalAnalysis technicalAnalysis: adviser.getITechnicalAnalysis()) {
                try {
                    CandleStick lastAddedCandleStickByCurrencyPair = candleStickService.getLatestByCurrencyPair(technicalAnalysis.getCurrencyPair());
                    technicalAnalysis.updateAlgorithms(lastAddedCandleStickByCurrencyPair);
                    logger.info(technicalAnalysis.getCurrencyPair() + " has candlesticks");
                }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    logger.warn(technicalAnalysis.getCurrencyPair() + " has no candlesticks");
                }

            }
            adviser.calculateAnalyses();
        }
    }, periodicTrigger);
}



@Bean
    public PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger() {
        PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger =  new PeriodicTrigger(TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_DATABASE_TO_FILL, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        periodicTrigger.setInitialDelay(1);

        return periodicTrigger;
    }
```

Comment: how long does each task run?

Comment: can't tell. could be a few seconds maybe 10-15 at max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling). Be default there will be only one thread for scheduler.
So what you can do is you can schedule the tasks one after the other may be a second apart.  This way second task will always run after first task.
Even if first task is not completed and schedule time for second task has reached, second task will have to wait for the thread from first task to be released.
You can also explicitly set the thread count for the scheduler with a bean declaration like this

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(THREAD_COUNT);// use 1 for this use case
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Comment: This is what I came up with after your advice.